Analyzing the behavior of derivatives for invertible functions over finite fields
Question
Let $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ denote the $p$-element field for a prime $p>3$ and let $S$ be the set of functions from $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ to $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Find all functions  $D\colon S\to S$ satisfying
$$D(f\circ g)=(D(f)\circ g)\cdot D(g)$$
for all $f,g \in {S}$. Here, $\circ$ denotes the function composition, so $(f\circ g)(x)$ is the function $f(g(x))$, and $\cdot$ denotes the pointwise multiplication, so $(f\cdot g)(x)=f(x)g(x)$.

My Attempt
Let $G$ be the set of invertible functions from $\mathbb{F}_p$ to $\mathbb{F}_p$, which can be naturally associated with the symmetric group $S_p$. We define a function $D: G \to \mathbb{F}_p^\times$, and we are interested in understanding the form that $D$ can take for different types of permutations.
To find the properties of $D$, we start by considering some basic cases. First, let $id \in G$ denote the identity permutation, which satisfies $id(x) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$. We hypothesize that for any such identity permutation, $D(id)(x)$ should be a constant function. More specifically, if we assume that $D(id)(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$, we can proceed by testing this assumption with other permutations.
Next, consider a simple transposition $\sigma = [u, v]$, where $u \neq v$. In this case, since $\sigma^2 = id$, applying $D$ to both sides gives
$$D(\sigma^2)(x) = D(id)(x) = 1,$$
$$D(\sigma)(x)^2 = 1,$$
Now, we extend this reasoning to cycles. Let $r = [a_0, a_1, \dots, a_{p-3}]$ be a cycle in $S_p$. Since $r^{p-2} = id$, applying $D$ again yields
$$D(r^{p-2})(x) = D(id)(x) = 1,$$
$$D(r)(x)^{p-2} = 1.$$
At this stage, my approach breaks down as I'm unsure how to generalize these observations to arbitrary permutations.
The above is an attempt by my friend since I wasn’t able to make any progress. I also don’t know if her attempt is right or not.

Are you sure that $D$ should not satisfy Leibniz's rule ?

I took the liberty to adjust the definition of multiplication, Feel free to roll it back if I misunderstood anything.
